# Creating query filters for Azure Table Service from base class

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, azure, expression

Please consider the code below:

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseClassHandler
    Public MustInherit Class MyOwnBaseClass
        Inherits TableEntity

        Public Property Val As Integer
    End Class

    Protected Function BuildFilter(PK As String, RK As String) As Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of MyOwnBaseClass, Boolean))

        Return Function(entity) entity.PartitionKey = PK And entity.RowKey = RK

    End Function
End Class

Public Class ClassHandler_A
    Inherits BaseClassHandler

    Public Class MyOwnClass_A
        Inherits BaseClassHandler.MyOwnBaseClass

        Public Property Val_A As Integer

        Public Sub New()
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Function RetrieveEntity(Table As CloudTable, RowKey As String, PartitionKey As String) As MyOwnClass_A
        ' Following line gives me a build error
        Return Table.CreateQuery(Of MyOwnClass_A).Where(MyBase.BuildFilter(RowKey, PartitionKey)).SingleOrDefault()
    End Function
End Class

Public Class ClassHandler_B
    Inherits BaseClassHandler

    Public Class MyOwnClass_B
        Inherits BaseClassHandler.MyOwnBaseClass

        Public Property Val_B As Integer

        Public Sub New()
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Function RetrieveEntity(Table As CloudTable, RowKey As String, PartitionKey As String) As MyOwnClass_B
        ' Following line gives me a build error
        Return Table.CreateQuery(Of MyOwnClass_B).Where(MyBase.BuildFilter(RowKey, PartitionKey)).SingleOrDefault()
    End Function
End Class
```

Here I have 2 base classes which are inherited by other two classes per type.
What I am trying to accomplish is to have a base method that could build the filter to be then used in the derived classes.

But of course the afore reported code gives me an error beacuse the filter is "build" for a `MyOwnBaseClass` and not for any of its derived ones:

```
Error   1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible `Where` can be called with these arguments:
[...]
    Extension method `Public Function Where(predicate As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of MyOwnClass_A, Boolean))) As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of MyOwnClass_A)` defined in `System.Linq.Queryable`: Value of type `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of Test.Form1.BaseClassHandler.MyOwnBaseClass, Boolean))` cannot be converted to `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of Test.Form1.ClassHandler_A.MyOwnClass_A, Boolean))`
[...]
```

Is there a way to achieve my purpose **without having to build the filter string myself**?

I couldn't add the `C#` tag because it re-colours the VB posted code in C# fashion, but I would also accept C# in the answer.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Alright, my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved it twice: one with `Expressions.Expression.Lambda` to "convert" my "base" expression into a new one for the inherited entity classes and a second one, even more simple, with Type Constraints, like so:

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseClassHandler
    Public MustInherit Class MyOwnBaseClass
        Inherits TableEntity

        Public Property Val As Integer
    End Class

    Protected Function BuildFilter(Of MyOwnClassT As {MyOwnBaseClass, New})(PK As String, RK As String) As Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of MyOwnClassT, Boolean))
        Dim f As Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of MyOwnClassT, Boolean)) =
            Function(e) e.PartitionKey = PK And e.RowKey = RK

        Return f
    End Function
End Class
```

... and it worked like a charm, I love it!

Thanks to ALL comunity of StackOverflow for the `Expressions.Expression.Lambda` solution, thou!